# Call to ExecuteTemplate receives an i/o timeout error

Tags: go

I have a function that makes a call to an external API using a Go http.Client, parses the result, and uses the result in the template executed afterwards.  Occasionally, the external API will respond slowly (~20s), and the template execution will fail citing "i/o timeout", or more specifically,

`template: :1:0: executing "page.html" at <"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\...>: write tcp 127.0.0.1:35107: i/o timeout`

This always coincides with a slow API response, but there is always a valid response in the JSON object, so the http.Client is receiving a proper response.  I am just wondering if anyone could point me towards what could be causing the i/o timeout in the ExecuteTemplate call.

I have tried ResponseHeaderTimeout and DisableKeepAlives in the client transport (both with and without those options) to no avail.  I've also tried setting the request's auto-close value to true to no avail.  A stripped-down version of the template generation code is below:

```
func viewPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    tmpl := pageTemplate{}

    duration, _ := time.ParseDuration("120s")
    tr := &http.Transport{
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: duration,
        DisableKeepAlives:     true,
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/some_function", nil)
    req.Close = true
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var res api_response // some struct that matches the JSON response
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &res)

    t, _ := template.New("page.html")
    err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", tmpl)
}
```

Comment: Can you actually reproduce the error with this stripped-down version? I think no, since 1) response is downloaded and _then_ the template is run - so inside ExecuteTemplate there can't be any tcp timeouts; 2) your template doesn't use the response (body) at all.

Comment: 1.  Response is downloaded prior to template run in the full version, as well.  In all instances the api_response object has a proper response from the server `fmt.Printf`'d out to the console just before the timeout complaint.

2.  My template simply prints out text from the response body, but as said above, I'm `fmt.Printf` the response just before the timeout anyway so it is arriving.  I am wondering if for some reason the client isn't closing its connection properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout on this line:

```
err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", tmpl)
```

means that the *outgoing* response is timing out when being written into, so nothing you change in the locally created client should affect it. It also does make sense that a slow response from that client increases the chance of the timeout on `w`, since the deadline is set when the response is created, before your handler is called, so a slow activity from your handler will increase the chances of a timeout.

There's no write timeout on the [http.Server](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Server) instance used by [http.ListenAndServe](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe), so you must be setting the [Server.WriteTimeout](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Server) field explicitly on the created server.

As a side note, there are errors being ignored in that handler, which is a strongly discouraged practice.

Comment: Error checking was removed for brevity, hence my calling the code "stripped down".

Comment: This was it.  Thank-you for your clarification regarding the outgoing response bit.  This was extremely helpful and solved the problem exactly.